# Kaltura - onKdpReady never called

Tags: javascript, kaltura

My html code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>TEST</title>

</head> <body>  <object id="kaltura_player_1406237220" name="kaltura_player_1406237220" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowNetworking="all" allowScriptAccess="always" height="333" width="400" bgcolor="#000000" style="width: 400px; height: 333px;" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/searchmonkey/media/" rel="media:video"       resource="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an" data="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an">      <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />       <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />       <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />        <param name="flashVars" value="emptyF=onKdpReady&readyF=onKdpReady" />      <param name="movie" value="https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an" />

        <a rel="media:thumbnail" href="http://cdnbakmi.kaltura.com/p/1737042/sp/173704200/thumbnail/entry_id/1_jghjj7an/version/100000/acv/101"></a> <span property="dc:description" content=""></span> <span property="media:title" content="1mb.mp4"></span> <span property="media:width" content="400"></span> <span property="media:height" content="333"></span> <span property="media:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"></span> <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/products/video-platform-features">Video          Platform</a> <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Features/Video-Management">Video Management</a> <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Video-Solutions">Video Solutions</a> <a href="http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Features/Video-Player">Video Player</a>  </object> </body> </html>
```

My JS code

```
function onKdpReady(playerId) {
    alert("THIS IS NEVER CALLED");
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ugsr/2/

I Used this example:

http://www.kaltura.org/kdp_js_api_demo_page.html

I don't know if I am missing something or if this is a bug.

Also as a side question I would like it to be compatible with the HTML5 player, will this do the trick or I have do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use https and the test page is http - javascript communication must be in the same protocol.
in addition from some reason on the jsfiddler you need to put the function inside the html (dont ask me why)

exmaple:

```
        <object id="kaltura_player_1406237220" name="kaltura_player_1406237220" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowNetworking="all" allowScriptAccess="always" height="333" width="400" bgcolor="#000000" style="width: 400px; height: 333px;" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/searchmonkey/media/" rel="media:video"
        resource="http://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an" data="http://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an" />


    </object>
<script>
    function jsCallbackReady(pid){
alert(pid);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Itay, a small improvement to your code will just be to omit the http: <param name="movie" value="//cdnapisec.kaltura.com/index.php/kwidget/cache_st/1406237220/wid/_1737042/uiconf_id/25101282/entry_id/1_jghjj7an" />

Comment: You will be protocol agnostic